# Check if all objects have the property value of all other objects

Tags: java

I have a list of objects. These objects have a processname, amount and a date. I need every object to have all dates (if it doesnt exist add a new one with amount 0). So if I have 2 processnames: 'Inflate' and 'Deflate' and they have different dates: 'Inflate':12-01-2017 and 'Deflate': 13-01-2017. I need them to have the other object's dates.

I have the following code but it feels devious:

```
        HashSet<Date> dates = new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<String> processes = new HashSet<>();

        //Get all the unique values from the objects. processAmounts is the list of objects
        for (ProcessAmount processAmount : processAmounts) {
            dates.add(processAmount.getDate());
            processes.add(processAmount.getProcessName());
        }

        //Loop through processnames
        for (String s : processes) {
            //Loop through all the unique dates
            for(Date date : dates) {
                //loop through the objects we have and check if the date exists.
                boolean dateFound = false;
                for(ProcessAmount processAmount : processAmounts) {
                    if(processAmount.getProcessName() != null && processAmount.getProcessName().equals(s)) {
                        if(processAmount.getDate().equals(date)) {
                            dateFound = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //If the date is not found add a new object with amount 0
                if(!dateFound) {
                    processAmounts.add(new ProcessAmount(date, 0, s));
                }
            }
        }
```

It might be a bit unclear for some people so if you don't understand I will try to explain it another way.

Comment: *"These objects have a processname, amount and a date. I need every object to have all dates"* does *all* actually mean *both*?

Comment: what is the *object* your explanation refers to?

Comment: *" 'Inflate':12-01-2017 and 'Deflate': 13-01-2017. I need them to have the other object's dates."*  Does this mean you want  'Inflate': **13**-01-2017 and 'Deflate': **12**-01-2017?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Yes exactly. I need all objects to have all the dates which exists in the list. So in this case I would end up with 4 objects.

Comment: I don't want to change the date btw. I want to add a new object with the correct date and 0 as amount.

Comment: is there a possibility that you already have *Inflate* and *Deflate* with the same date?

Comment: Yeah they can already be correct.

Answer (score 2):

From the question and the comment I'd argue that your object model needs refactoring. There should be an *Action* object (you might come up with a better name...) tat contains the *date* and both of the processes *Inflate* and *Deflate* (not having a date themselves).

However...

This is how I would approach this by avoiding to iterate `processAmounts` excessively

```
public void fixMissingProcesses(){
    Map<String,Map<Date,ProcessAmount>> processesPerName = separateProcessesByName();        
    List<String> processNames = new ArrayList<>(processesPerName.keySet());
    for(int i=1;i<processNames.length();i++)
      for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
         addMissingProcesses(processNames.get(i),processNames.get(j), processesPerName);
}    

private void separateProcessesByName(){
    Map<String,Map<Date,ProcessAmount>> processesPerName = new HasMap<>();        
    for (ProcessAmount processAmount : processAmounts) {
      if(null!=processAmount.getProcessName()){
         Map<Date,ProcessAmount> processesPerDate=  processesPerName.getOrDefault(processAmount.getProcessName(),new HashMap<>());
         processesPerDate.put(processAmount.getDate(),processAmount);
         processesPerName.put(processAmount.getProcessName(),processesPerDate)
      }
    }
    return processesPerName;
}    


private void addMissingProcesses(String sourceProcessName, String targetProcessName, Map<String,Map<Date,ProcessAmount>> processesPerName);
    for(Date checkDate: processesPerName.get(sourceProcessName).keySet()){
       if(!processesPerName.get(targetProcessName).containsKey(checkDate)){
         processAmounts.add(new  ProcessAmount(checkDate, 0, targetProcessName)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The amount of object's is not static though. So I will still need to loop in the first method.

Comment: Maybe, but only over the combinations of distinct *object* names... updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Code Improvements

I'll remain in original Java-7 style here, but some of the items might be expressed definitely better in functional Java-8 style.

#### Use Interfaces

```
HashSet<Date> dates = new HashSet<>();
```

In declarations, replace collection implementation types with interfaces:

```
Set<Date> dates = new HashSet<>();
```

It's just a cleaner practice: prefer interfaces over implementations.

#### Bug or Suspicious Comparison of Dates

The old `java.util.Date` are compared with `equals()`, which will lead to unpredictable behavior, because they are compared up to milliseconds. So two `Date`s created within even a short delay will not be equal. Just try this simple test:

```
@Test
public void compareDates() throws InterruptedException {
  Date date1 = new Date();
  Thread.sleep(50L);
  Date date2 = new Date();
  assertNotEquals(date1, date2); // they are not equal, although `toString()` will output the same value.
}
```

In the current code this looks like a bug: there is a high risk that multiple `ProcessAmount(date, 0, s)` are created for same date and `dateFound` is hard to ever become `true` in the loop.

"Java <= 7" solutions: 1) compare them through string representations, using formatted date output with pattern up to the searched granularity ("yyyy-MM-dd"); 2) compare year-month-day values; 3) ... other multiple inventive ways found on SO.

*Recommended solution*: throw `java.util.Date` away and use `LocalDate` from Java 8 or Joda-Time.

#### Conditions

This one

```
if(processAmount.getProcessName() != null && processAmount.getProcessName().equals(s)) { ...
```

looks heavy. In the original code `s` looks like it should not be nullable, so

```
if (s.equals(processAmount.getProcessName())) {
```

Or use

```
if (Objects.equals(s, processAmount.getProcessName())) { // supports nullability
```

### Design Improvements

Three nested `for` loops and conditionals create too much complexity. Really, too much.

The idea for improvement is:

1) Create a `Map` that associates a process name with its date. It will help us to know that the process having *this* name is associated with *this* date and that it needs to be associated with all the other known dates.

2) Iterate on the entries of the map. For each entry, create a collection of all unique dates and remove from it the date of the entry. Create a new `ProcessAmount` for all those dates and add it to the target list.

Here is how the whole solution might look like. `Date` is replaced with `LocalDate`:

```
Map<String, LocalDate> procNameToDate = new HashMap<>();
for (ProcessAmount processAmount : processAmounts) {
  procNameToDate.put(processAmount.getProcessName(), processAmount.getDate());
}

for (Map.Entry<String, LocalDate> nameToDateTuple : procNameToDate.entrySet()) {
  Collection<LocalDate> otherDates = new HashSet<>(procNameToDate.values());
  otherDates.remove(nameToDateTuple.getValue());
  for (LocalDate date : otherDates) {
    processAmounts.add(new ProcessAmount(date, 0, nameToDateTuple.getKey()));
  }
}
```